# SSIS Oracle and Distributed transactions

Tags: sql-server, oracle, transactions, ssis, distributed

We currently have ditributed transactons with 2 remote SQL servers and next week one of these databases is going to be migrated to Oracle.

I wanted to know if there are any known issues that i should plan around for workaround/fixing, when involving Oracle as part of the distributed transaction - i.e. our SSIS running a distributed transaction => distributed transaction participants being a remote SQL server, and an Oracle database (Oracle - installed in a non-windows OS).

Would this work at all in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

why are you migrating to oracle, are you indexed properly?

I think that you can do all of this with stored procedures, but I'm guessing that you're going to have to enable the DTC on the linked server

BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION TranName

INSERT INTO SqlServer.myDB.dbo.myTable(KeyID, Value)
Values (123, 'hello world')

INSERT INTO OracleServer.myScrewedUpOracleName.dbo.myTable(KeyID, Value)
Values (123, 'why oracle?')

COMMIT